# Is it possible to access pypiserver remotely within the local network

Tags: python, pypi

I've stumble upon pypiserver as an offline local pypi python packages/libraries repository.

The configuration on this [link](https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/#configuring-pip) only shows "localhost" setup, I would like to know if that local repo can be setup as a LAN repo?

Comment: The chapter at the link has this paragraph: «If you have installed pypiserver on a remote url…» so yes, it's possible. I don't think any additional configuration is required at the server side.

Comment: Yup, I have tried it and it was working. But some packages though return a no compatible package found even though the package is already in my package repository, some package working perfectly fine..

Answer (score 0):

As commented by [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd), the [link](https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/#configuring-pip) has a topic for the question I have raised. Instead of using "localhost", use the LAN IP address of the hosting machine e.g: `http://<ip-address>:<port>` to connect to the local pypiserver repo.